# C Programming: run a program through a loop?

Tags: c, loops

I am trying to write a program that counts your change and reports the total amount. I was able to write the function to calculate the change but I am not sure how to make it run in a loop. One more thing is that I want the user the press enter or return to exit when the program ask for their name but I am also not sure how. This is my first programming class and I am trying to get better. Thank you for your time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <time.h>

float countChange(int quarters, int dimes, int nickles, int pennies);

int main(void) 
{
  int a,b,c,d;
  char yourname[20];
  printf("Your total money is $ %0.2f \n", countChange(12,23,34,45));
  printf("What is your name (Return/Enter to quit)?");
  scanf("%s", yourname);
  printf("\nHow many quarters do you have? \n" );
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("\nHow many dimes do you have? \n" );
  scanf("%d", &b);
  printf("\nHow many nickles do you have? \n" );
  scanf("%d", &c);
  printf("\nHow many pennies do you have? \n" );
  scanf("%d", &d);
  printf("All counted, %s has $ %0.2f\n", yourname, countChange(a,b,c,d));
  return 0;
}

float countChange(int quarters, int dimes, int nickles, int pennies)
{
  float QuartersTotal, DimesTotal, NicklesTotal, PenniesTotal, total;
  QuartersTotal= quarters*0.25;
  DimesTotal= dimes*0.10;
  NicklesTotal= nickles*0.05;
  PenniesTotal= pennies*0.01;
  total= QuartersTotal+ DimesTotal+ NicklesTotal+ PenniesTotal;
  return total;
}
```

Comment: Which part do you want to put into a loop?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I want the program to keep asking the user for their name and numbers of coins they have until they press Enter or Return to exit. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, I've updated my answer to loop until they don't enter their name. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the code and added in the loop, hope this helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

float countChange(int quarters, int dimes, int nickles, int pennies)
{
    float QuartersTotal, DimesTotal, NicklesTotal, PenniesTotal, total;

    QuartersTotal= quarters*0.25;
    DimesTotal= dimes*0.10;
    NicklesTotal= nickles*0.05;
    PenniesTotal= pennies*0.01;
    total= QuartersTotal + DimesTotal + NicklesTotal + PenniesTotal;

    return total;
}

void getNumCoins(char *coinType, int *out)
{
    printf("\nHow many %s do you have?\n", coinType);
    if (scanf("%d", out) <= 0) {
        printf("Please enter a valid integer\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    char yourname[20];

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Your total money is $ %0.2f \n", countChange(12,23,34,45));
        printf("What is your name (Return/Enter to quit)?");
        scanf("%s", yourname);

        if (yourname[0] == '\n') break;

        getNumCoins("quarters", &a);
        getNumCoins("dimes", &b);
        getNumCoins("nickels", &c);
        getNumCoins("pennies", &d);

        printf("All counted, %s has $ %0.2f\n", yourname, countChange(a,b,c,d));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you explicitly want a loop, I can edit my answer to show that as well, but in your case I don't think it will make it too much cleaner.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the %s in the scanf("%s", out); should be %d right?

Comment: Yup that's a typo on my part. Good on you for catchign that.

Comment: You should always check if `scanf` has parse error (happens easily with `%d` format specifier), and do something appropriate, maybe `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or `*out = 0` or whatever. Currently this program has undefined behavior (uninitialized variables) if user writes "3 quarters" as an answer to first question, for example.

Comment: I was trying to keep my code as close as possible to the original code given, but it's probably best to show good practices early.

Comment: the `yourname[0]` is the first character of `yourname`. Basically, if they didn't enter a name and just pressed enter, the only thing in `yourname` is that enter character, so I'm just checking for that. If that's the case, we want to exit from the loop, using `break`.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Thank you a lot for your help. I am trying to make the program to print out Bye when the user input nothing at the What is your name. I put the printf("Bye) before the break but nothing printed out. Maybe I did something wrong here.

Comment: Can you post the code? I suspect you're missing braces or soemthing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should use **fgets** instead of **scanf** for reading arbitrary length strings, it is safer. (avoid overflow)

```
while (1)
{
    printf("Your total money is $ %0.2f \n", countChange(12, 23, 34, 45));
    printf("What is your name (Return/Enter to quit)?");

    fgets(yourname, sizeof(yourname), stdin);

    if (yourname[0] == '\n')
        break;

    printf("\nHow many quarters do you have? \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nHow many dimes do you have? \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("\nHow many nickles do you have? \n");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("\nHow many pennies do you have? \n");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    printf("All counted, %s has $ %0.2f\n", yourname, countChange(a, b, c, d));
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program to keep asking the user, you can simply use:

```
FILE
getline
scanf OR fscanf ...
```

to get it.

For example,

```
FILE * prompt = stdin;
int result = 0;
while ((int)(result = getline(&line, &capacity, prompt)) != -1) {Your code here}
```

What this code is doing is essentially:

**1. read from the standard input**

**2. Read the line from the input until it is told to stop**

This code will run forever unless the user wants quit or the program exits.
It will exit when given command + D or command + C, which are kill commands.